# Is there a way to test race conditions in python?

Tags: python, testing, race-condition

I realise that this question in and of itself probably makes little sense - by nature it must be very difficult to test for positivity of race conditions, and near impossible for negativity.

I'm using SQLAlchemy to interact with a Postgres database and was wondering if anyway there was a certain package that might help trigger a race condition?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by race condition in this context?

Comment: Ensuring safe update operations on rows in the database when there are multiple processes

Comment: The database should be able to ensure that (if you use it correctly).

Comment: So would you say, if implemented correctly, testing is somewhat a futile exercise?

Comment: I don't think this question is very clear. If you have specific code that you think is vulnerable to a race condition, you can artificially create one and verify that your code performs correctly. If you *don't* have specific code you're asking about, there's really no way to answer this question.